# MDL add ripple effect when clicking 'mdl-navigation__link'

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

I have such navigation:

```
<nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <a id="submenu" class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
</nav>
```

When `<a>` element clicked I want to add ripple effect on it with accent color.
And then I want this element stayed selected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT : Note that, per request from OP, this answer has been edited to reflect *his* needs. If you came because of the title, check the other answer below. This answer is to keep the link selected after the ripple effect finishes. (Cf his comments where he asks for that)

---

You can easily add the ripple effect by setting `class="mdl-navigation__link mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon"` on your tags. However, since the `<a>` tag isn't meant to do that, we add some css to make it work :

```
a.mdl-js-ripple-effect {
  display: inline-block;//Important, without that the button won't appear correctly
  position: relative; //without it, ripple will be shifted

  width: 50px; //Same as height, for a perfect circle
  height: 50px; // Works with % values too
  line-height: 50px; //same as button height, to center the text vertically
  text-align: center; //Center horizontally 
}
```

Then, you don't want the ripple effect to disappear on the last clicked element. You can do that with some JQuery :

```
$('a.mdl-js-ripple-effect').click(function() {
$('a.mdl-js-ripple-effect').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

When you click on any button, this code will remove the class 'selected' (or whatever you want) of every button, before adding it again to the one you clicked only.
Then we style the selected class to keep the ripple effect.

```
.selected .mdl-ripple {//.selected is the class we used in javascript
  width: 0; //necessary, or it will be shifted
  opacity: 0.3; //To keep the ripple effect visible
}
```

You can try it in this Fiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AmineIzumi/u5x5mkko/)

Comment: How to make only one item being selected?

Comment: @sreginogemoh I updated my fiddle and answer to do that, with JQuery however. You actually didn't specified if you wanted a css-only answer, and most of MDL works with JS, so I assumed it was okay. Check it out !

Answer (score 4):

Just using the classes **class="mdl-navigation__link mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"**

And adding the css:

```
a.mdl-js-ripple-effect { position: relative; }
```

will do the trick, no need for all the other classes and javascript.

Comment: Hi ! Almost a year after, I just noticed your answer to his question - Indeed, you answer the question"MDL add ripple effect when clicking 'mdl-navigation__link'" and that's the answer everyone would be looking for with this title. But OP refined his request to ask that the ripple effect should stay "active" after the link was clicked, which is why I edited my answer, and is why your answer doesn't quite reflect his needs and wasn't "accepted". However with the question title your answer is the correct one so you'll have my upvote on this :) .